# Automatic updates for Audio Units

Tags: macos, audiounit, automatic-updates

We would like to implement automatic updates for our 
Audio Unit plugin (Synthesizer).

Can anybody suggest a mechanism for accomplishing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of mechanisms for doing so.

[eSellerate](http://www.esellerate.net/) is a commercial solution that has features for the desired functionality.

Or, your audio unit can be structured into two components: a shell; and a core dylib. The shell uses http to find the latest version for your customer's product, and downloads the new core dylib into a temp location. Then, either automatically, or through user confirmation, the shell swaps in the new core dylib.

FWIW, the above is a technique that can be also be used for content (e.g., samples, presets, etc.).

Alternatively, a semi automatic technique would be to use http to find the latest version for your customer's product. And then prompt the user to download the latest dmg.

Comment: What do you say about this idea: since it's a bundle (AU), change the MacOs permission to 777, when a new update available, download it to this directory and change the CFBundleExecutable inside the Info.plist to the new file?

Comment: That is a clever method. However, you may want to consider the following. Though your installer may have run as admin (for a number of reasons, including where the AU is located in the file system, etc.), your AU may not have the permissions to perform the method above. On the other hand, you can have your AU operate where it has appropriate permissions.